# How should we write keywords of a webpage

Tags: seo, pagerank, keywords

I would like to know how to write the keywords in head section.

Either it should be comma separated or white space separated?

Comment: Keep in mind that the meta keywords have no effect on your page's ranking.

Comment: so for what are they used for?

Comment: Google doesn't use the meta keywords, but I would wager that the smaller search engines probably still do. Remember that Google isn't the ONLY search engine. That said, it never hurts to put it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keywords should be comma separated, unless it is a group of words that makeup the keyword (Like FirstName LastName) then use white space.

Comment: it is called *a phrase* :p